# how to remove 404 error in angular js?

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, ionic-framework

```
.factory('ChartService', ['$http','$q',
        function ChartService($http,$q) {
            // interface

            // implementation
            var canceler = $q.defer();

            function getTableData() {

                return  $http.post('http://202.429.115.52:9906/oo/api.php?request=getSubfunctionWiseHCAndSW').success(function (data) {
                    if (data.mm == "No Data Available"){
                        localData();
                    }
                    return data;


                }).error(function(error){
                    alert("error")
                   canceler.resolve();
                    localData()
                  //  console.log(error)
                });



                }

            function localData(){
                        alert("loaddata")
               return  $http.get('vro/hcswc.json').success(function(response){
                    console.log(response+"==");
                    return response;
                }).error(function(error){
                    console.log(error);
                });
            }




            return {
                getTableData:getTableData
            }
        }
    ]);
```

**Error**
**XMLHttpRequest cannot load http://192.127.215.52:9906/api.php?request=getSubfunctionrection. No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource. Origin 'http://localhost:63342' is therefore not allowed access. The response had HTTP status code 404.**

**App.js // resolve Code**

```
.state('app.vro', {
        url: "/vro/:isfirstActiveState",
        views: {
          'menuContent': {
            controller: "vrobCtrl",
            templateUrl: 'vrob/vrob.html'


            }
        }  ,
          resolve: {
              tableData:function(ChartService){

                  return ChartService.getTableData();
              }



          }
      })
```

Hello 
I am trying to get data form service .I have one condition while calling webservice .the condition is if I will get error then I get request from local in other words if I get any error from server than I need to read json file  from local . I need to use resolve and call my service and use that data on controller .my **localData**  is not returning data to resolve .what is the problem in my code ..

here is one example
http://plnkr.co/edit/0y9V0m2hmsUBRXoeyjig?p=preview
I am getting error correct but it should load data from local json .why it is not loading data from local json

Comment: Looks like you need to enable CORS on the server you are trying to get data from. 
What language is the server running on?

Comment: I am just reading json flle ..but in angular we can read json file

Comment: @penne12 question has nothing to do with CORS...it's how to manage returning another promise if first one is rejected

Comment: Yeah. I know - but browsers need a CORS to read data - it prevents weird hacks from happening. Where is this page hosted (url)?  If it's not on `http://202.129.215.52:9906`, you'll need to tell us what server you use.

Comment: @charlietfl Yeah - I know, but he will always have an error on his server if he doesn't resolve CORS.

Comment: @charlietfl so what is solution if first promises is rejected

Comment: @penne12 you are not understanding the question how to resolve when first request is rejected

Comment: I think in this situation you will not be able to return the first `$http` and will have to use `$q` and resolve if first request is successful and return second request if not

Comment: Please provide example with plunker as I give one plunker please use that plunker .and edit it.But situation is that i need to use resolve

Comment: in the `$http.error of server call` you need to use `return $http.get('path.to.json')`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is an anti-pattern to use `$q` to manage `$http` requests but in this situation I don't know another way:

```
function getTableData() {

  var deferred = $q.defer();

  $http.post('http://202.129.215.52:9906/mondelez/api.php?request=getSubfunctionWiseHCAndSW')
    .then(
      // resolve callback
      function(data) {
        deferred.resolve(data.data)
        return data.data;
      },
      // reject callback make different request
      function(err) {
        $http.get('data.json').success(function(response) {
          deferred.resolve(response);              
        }).error(function(error) {
          deferred.reject()
        });

      })

  return deferred.promise;

}
```

<kbd>**[DEMO](http://plnkr.co/edit/gQcLjVG9URRx86BzrpEL?p=preview)**</kbd>

Comment: Where did you read that it's an anti pattern? There are certainly benefits to only passing one type of promise throughout the application.

Comment: @soote `$http` already returns a promise http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23803743/what-is-the-explicit-promise-construction-antipattern-and-how-do-i-avoid-it

Comment: The http promise has a different interface than the q promise, meaning you now need to know which type of promise you are dealing with.